# How to invoke iPhone Maps for Directions with Current Location as Start Address

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I know it's possible to start the iPhone maps application by calling `openURL` on a google maps URL with parameters `saddr` and `daddr` with location strings or Lat/Long (see example below).

But I'm wondering if it's possible to make the start address be the **"Current Location"** maps bookmark so that I can use the **Maps** app's location handling code. My Google search has been pretty fruitless.

For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@", myLatLong, latlong]]];
```

Except with something to invoke the current location bookmark in place of `myLatLong`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this same exact functionality and I have maps loading just fine with the destination however when I load google maps it gives me the last known GPS reading, even if it's hours or days out of date. Sometimes it gives me location readings that are a mile or more off...

How do I get accurate Current Location readings? Am I missing something with CoreLocation's accuracy?

thx

Answer (score 137):

### Pre iOS 6

You need to use Core Location to get the current location, but with that lat/long pair, you can get Maps to route you from there, to a street address or location.  Like so:

```objc
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [self getCurrentLocation];
// this uses an address for the destination.  can use lat/long, too with %f,%f format
NSString* address = @"123 Main St., New York, NY, 10001";
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",
                    currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude,
                    [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Finally, if you do want to avoid using CoreLocation to explicitly find the current location, and want to use the `@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@"` url instead, then [see this link that I provided in comments below](http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps) for how to localize the **Current+Location** string.  However, you are taking advantage of another undocumented feature, and as Jason McCreary points out below, it may not work reliably in future releases.

---

### Update for iOS 6

Originally, **Maps** used Google maps, but now, Apple and Google have separate maps apps.

**1)** If you wish to route using the Google Maps app, use [the comgooglemaps URL scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#directions):

```objc
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%@&directionsmode=driving",
                    [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
BOOL opened = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

**2)** To use Apple Maps, you can use the new `MKMapItem` class for iOS 6.  [See the Apple API docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem)

Basically, you will use something like this, if routing to destination *coordinates* (`latlong`):

```objc
    MKPlacemark* place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate: latlong addressDictionary: nil];
    MKMapItem* destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark: place];
    destination.name = @"Name Here!";
    NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destination, nil];
    NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, 
                                 MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];
    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems: items launchOptions: options];
```

In order to support both iOS 6+ and pre iOS 6 in the same code, I'd recommend using something like this code that Apple has on the `MKMapItem` API doc page:

```objc
Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
   // iOS 6 MKMapItem available
} else {
   // use pre iOS 6 technique
}
```

This would assume that your Xcode Base SDK is iOS 6 (or **Latest iOS**).

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary. See the answer by @bob below where you pass "Current+Location" as a parameter

Comment: @Willster: If someone can figure out how to get Current Location to work as a param on iPad, I'm sold!!

Comment: Actually, Willster .. it's not more complicated than necessary.  Look at the date of this thread.  There was no OS 4.0.  On 3.x, you needed to pass in the coordinates.  As Joe alludes to, you've still got plenty of iPads still on 3.2, not to mention iPod Touches, or iPhones where users just don't get around to upgrading.  Plus, there's the issue of localization.  If the user's not using English, Current+Location doesn't work.  So, if you want your solution to be robust, you need to pass the coordinates.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590972/open-maps-app-from-code-where-how-to-find-the-current-location/4934381#4934381 for the part about localization.

Comment: "Y'know, I think I've learned something today." Embrace the coordinates. :)

Comment: Sorry- @Nate: you were right. The Current+Location technique is not robust. This solution is probably best.

Comment: It looks like someone was nice enough to post a list of localized equivalents of "Current+Location".  (http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps)  So, that part may now be less of an issue.

Comment: Although `Current+Location` worked before, this no longer seems to work on iOS 5.1.1.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, thanks for the update. I certainly agree that staying away from `Current+Location` seems most robust, especially since the code to simply get the lat/long current location from `CLLocationManager`, or `MKMapView` is not very complicated.  I've updated my answer with your comment!

Comment: can we add annotation of address/location while opening this map.

Comment: @MohitJethwa, please use [the Ask Question button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to ask a new question. Comment sections are not for new questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

```
NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Current Location&saddr=%@",startAddr];
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
[url release];
```

This works but only when the iPhone/iPod language is set in English. If you want to support other languages you'll have to use a localized string to match the Maps bookmark name.

Comment: Works for me on iPhone but not on iPad. In the latter case I end up starting at Current, MO. :(

Comment: I don't have an iPad to test that, but what is the name of the bookmark for current position in iPad Map app ?

Comment: In US English (at least), it shows up as "Current Location" ... unless that is _already_ set as a start/endpoint ... then it is absent from the bookmark list.

Comment: What a shame we need to translate it ...I am sure there is a special code, but which ...

Comment: Although it worked before, this no longer seems to work on iOS 5.1.1.

Comment: can we set destination name as well?

Answer (score 11):

This works on iPhone:

> [http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current Location&daddr=123 Main St,Ottawa,ON](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=123%20Main%20St,Ottawa,ON)

Comment: You have to encode the spaces, but yes, this works. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590972/open-maps-app-from-code-where-how-to-find-the-current-location

Comment: Works very well on iPhone! On iPad I manage to land on - I kid you not - Current, MO. :-o

Comment: this doesn't work. i just tried on my iphone (4.2.6). docs say it ought to, but it doesn't

Comment: Use "Current+Location" instead. Worked for me.

Comment: This solution only works if the user has set their phone language to English.

Comment: You can't have spaces in the address, they have to be encoded

Answer (score 10):

You can use a preprocessor #define like:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

to understand your iOS version. Then, I can use this code to support iOS 6, too:

```
NSString* addr = nil;
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
   addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=Posizione attuale", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
} else {
   addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=Posizione attuale", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
}

NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 5):

Because of sandboxing, you don't have access to the Map application's bookmarks.

Instead, use Core Location to determine the current location yourself. Then use that location (the lat and long) in the URL you build to open Maps.

Comment: I can't see how sandboxing would be relevant to asking Maps to use the Current Location. This is a nonsense answer.

Comment: I believe the answer refers to the fact that "Current Location" is among the bookmarks in the Maps application, and that apps don't have access to those bookmarks. Not nonsense, just missing that connection.

Comment: I suspect that using "Current Location" (or the URI-encoded variant) is amounting to a "happy accident" on iPhone/iPod touch only, in that it just happens to work in spite of itself. (That there is I18N to account for is enough to convince me - stick with coordinates!)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend checking out [CMMapLauncher](https://github.com/citymapper/CMMapLauncher), a mini-library that I built to launch Apple, Google, and other iOS mapping apps with a specific mapping request.  With CMMapLauncher, the code to get the directions in your question would be:

```
[CMMapLauncher launchMapApp:CMMapAppAppleMaps
          forDirectionsFrom:[CMMapPoint mapPointWithName:@"Origin"
                                              coordinate:myLatLong]
                         to:[CMMapPoint mapPointWithName:@"Destination"
                                              coordinate:latlong]];
```

As you can see, it also encapsulates the version checking required between iOS 6 & others.

Answer (score 3):

Hey since iOS6 is out!

Apple did something remarkable in a bad way (from my point of view).

Apple's maps are launched and for devices running iOS 6 you should not use `maps.google.com/?q=` if you want the iDevice to open the native Plan app. Now it would be `maps.apple.com/?q=`.

So that developers don't have to much work, the friendly maps.apple.com server redirects all non-Apple devices to maps.google.com so the change is transparent.

This way we developpers just have to switch all google query strings to apple ones.
This is what I dislike a lot.

I had to implement that functionnality today so I did it. But I felt I should not just rewrite every url lying in mobile website to target Apple's maps server so I thought I'd just detect iDevices server-side and serve apple urls just for those. I thought I'd share.

I'm using PHP so I used the opensource Mobile Detect library : http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Just use the `isiPad` pseudo method as a boolean getter and you're done, you wont convert google into apple ;-)

```
$server=$detect->isiPad()?"apple":"google";
$href="http://maps.{$server}.com/?q=..."
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this now in html just from a url on your mobile device only. Here's an [example](http://maps.google.com/maps/m?dc=mgc_maps#ll=43.600113,-116.198677&z=13&saddr=My%20Location&daddr=1910%20university%20dr%20Boise%20id&ttype=dep&dirflg=d&view=map&l-view=map&l-lci=m,com.google.latitudepublicupdates&ac=t,l,). The cool thing is if you turn this into a qr code you have a way of someone getting directions to you from wherever they are just by scanning it on their phone.

Answer (score 2):

The real solution can be found here. [Z5 Concepts iOS Development Code Snippet](http://z5concepts.com/z5blog/post/How-To-Use-Current-Location-in-iOS-Maps-App.aspx)

It just requires a little bit of encoding.

```
- (IBAction)directions1_click:(id)sender
{
    NSString* address = @"118 Your Address., City, State, ZIPCODE";
    NSString* currentLocation = @"Current Location";
    NSString* url = [NSStringstringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",[currentLocation stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplicationsharedApplication];
    [app openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS6 the apple docs recommend using the equivalent maps.apple.com URL Scheme

so use

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f
```

instead of

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f
```

to be backwards compatible the code would be

```
    NSString* versionNum = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *nativeMapScheme = @"maps.apple.com";
    if ([versionNum compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
        nativeMapScheme = @"maps.google.com";
    }
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", nativeMapScheme
             startCoordinate.latitude, startCoordinate.longitude,
             endCoordinate.latitude, endCoordinate.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

there is a whole load of other supported parameters for the Apple Maps URL scheme : [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf)

you can use these iOS version detection macros if you have conditional code in other parts of your code. [iOS version macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8042056/143318)

Comment: Good post on the maps URL scheme, but you should generally **not** test the OS version number this way.  `systemVersion` is not a float (e.g. `5.1.1` is not a float), and that comparison can actually yield the incorrect result.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to ask for location permissions and don't have the lat and lng, use the following.

```
NSString *destinationAddress = @"Amsterdam";

Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:destinationAddress completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count] > 0) {

            MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];

            MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

            MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];


            NSArray *mapItems = @[mapItem, mapItem2];

            NSDictionary *options = @{
        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
        MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:
            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeStandard],
        MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES
            };

            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];

        } else {
            //error nothing found
        }
    }];
    return;
} else {

    NSString *sourceAddress = [LocalizedCurrentLocation currentLocationStringForCurrentLanguage];

    NSString *urlToOpen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",
                 [sourceAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                 [destinationAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToOpen]];
}
```

For ios5, the Current Location needs to be in the correct language. I use the LocalizedCurrentLocation from this post http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps

For ios6, I use the CLGeocoder to get the placemark and then open the map with it and the current location.

Remember to add CoreLocation.framework and MapKit.framework

Answer (score 1):

For iOS6 Maps App, you can just use the same URL posted above 
`http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@`

but instead of the Google maps URL, you use the url with `maps://` resulting in the following URL: `maps://saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@.`

Using 'Current Location' doesn't seem to work, so I stayed with the coordinates.

Antother good thing: It's backwards compatible: On iOS5, it launches the Google Maps app.

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of Google Maps, simply omit the `sadr` parameter:

> `saddr`: … If the value is left blank, then the user’s current location will be used.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be using [OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS](https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS) as this is an up to date choice (by November 2015), it supports cocoa pods installation and you are ready to go in a few clicks.

Install using: `pod "OpenInGoogleMaps"`

Require in header file using: `#import "OpenInGoogleMapsController.h"`

Sample code below:

```
/*In case the user does NOT have google maps, then apple maps shall open*/
[OpenInGoogleMapsController sharedInstance].fallbackStrategy = kGoogleMapsFallbackAppleMaps;    

/*Set the coordinates*/
GoogleMapDefinition *definition = [[GoogleMapDefinition alloc] init];   
CLLocationCoordinate2D metsovoMuseumCoords;     //coordinates struct
metsovoMuseumCoords.latitude = 39.770598;
metsovoMuseumCoords.longitude = 21.183215;
definition.zoomLevel = 20;
definition.center = metsovoMuseumCoords;        //this will be the center of the map

/*and here we open the map*/
[[OpenInGoogleMapsController sharedInstance] openMap:definition];
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this on a different thread. ([Current Location doesn't work with Apple Maps IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539009/current-location-doesnt-work-with-apple-maps-ios-6/14272263#14272263)). You need to get the coordinates of the current location first, then use it to create the map url.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide source location, it will take current location as source. Try below code-

let urlString = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=(destinationLocation.latitude),(destinationLocation.longitude)&dirflg=d"
        }

UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlString)!)