# Translate String in a language (English) to other language (phone's current language) using built-in API

Tags: objective-c, iphone, dictionary, cocoa-touch

I am calling Google Maps app to show directions between "Current Location" and another location.  I am using the following code,

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                 @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%f,%f", 
                 @"Current\%20Location", 
                 destCoordinate.latitude, destCoordinate.longitude];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Note that I am passing **@"Current\%20Location"** as *saddr*. This works fine if my phone's *Language* is set to **English**. @pazustep, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590972/open-maps-app-from-code-where-how-to-find-the-current-location/4934381#4934381), in my post regarding finding Current Location, suggested that this wont work if the *Language* is different. And obviously, to solve this issue, I have to use **Core Location** to find the current location and pass the *latitude* and *longitude* to Google Maps app. But I am expecting some other way to solve this issue without modifying the implementation logic.

1. Is there any built-in API available to translate the string **"Current Location"** , or any string, into the current phone *Language*?
2. If not, Is there a way to tell Google Maps app to translate the string to the current language?

Comment: I like this question, but I figure that you're going to end up translating the string with some other web service. Have you tried adding the &hl=en parameter to the URL so that the search gets performed in english?

Comment: @Aurum Aquila: Now I tried this.. It doesn't work though..

Comment: Why are you escaping the `%` with a ` \ `

Comment: @JeremyP: This post has the answer for your question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590972/open-maps-app-from-code-where-how-to-find-the-current-location/4591072#4591072

Comment: @Simon: You are not doing format substitution on the string `@"Current%20Location"`  In any case, the correct escape for `%` in format strings is `%%` http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW2

Answer (score 1):

Why not use core location to get the latitude and longitude of the current location and put that in to saddr?