# Converting 'Current Location' Languages OR passing lon/lat

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

To whoever that can help,

My question comes from another topic @ [Open Maps app from Code - Where/How to find the "Current Location"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590972/open-maps-app-from-code-where-how-to-find-the-current-location). 
Did anyone successfully use the source code from martip @ http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps with the ‘LocalizedCurrentLocation.zip’ file?

I've been trying but I'm not sure where I should place the example codes & how to 'call' the strings. I'm sorry for posting such newbie question but I have no where else to go~

I’ve been trying to work with it but I’m kinda lost. I’m not sure how to ‘call’ the localized string and use the ‘example usage’. I apologize for asking such a newbie question.

Please help me out here as I’m scratching my head over this matter. Anyone? Please~
Thanks in advance!^^

P/S: I'm actually trying to open iPhone maps from my app with directions from 'Current Location'. I know there are 2 ways of doing it; by CoreLocation (pass lon/lat) and replacing 'Current Location' with Strings BUT as I mention I'm a real beginner here and would appreciate it if anyone can advise & instruct me on which way is better & how to accomplish it. Btw, I'm using jquery and phonegap.

Answer (score 3):

I have just completed the same task for current location. I came to know that, probably u also know that, we can't get current location in simulator. For just checking that is ur app working for location, u can add .gpx file and set ur current static location. 
This is what I know...:)

Comment: Hi Goti, yea...i know that simulator can't open map. I uses actual device to test. But I can't change the '...saddr=Current Location...' according to device language OR long/lat. Do you have any idea?Thanks!^^

Comment: No airriq, simulator can open map but can't find current location of yours. Default it shows u San Fransisco's location. And as I said u, u can add .gpx file and set ur current location in it....I have tested wht I have done...and it worked fine.....Good luck.:)