# iOS 5: willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration not called when first loading controller

Tags: ios5, orientation

I've implemented this method in my code to know when an interface orientation change will occur:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I rely on this to be called to setup my views.  In either iOS 4 or 5 it gets called properly when the orientation *changes*.

In iOS 4 it also gets called when the controller first loads (regardless of if the orientation changes or not, it gets called once at the beginning with the correct orientation).

The problem is I noticed in iOS 5 this does not happen anymore.  The method gets called when the orientation changes but not when the controller initially loads.  This is a problem for me because I rely on this to setup the initial view placement based on the orientation.

Any ideas why this behaviour changed?  What's the best way to handle this?  Should I check what the orientation is in viewDidLoad if on iOS 5 and then manually call the willRotate and didRotate methods?  This feels a bit like a hack.

Thanks for any input you can provide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since I'm pressed for time I've had to work around this odd behaviour and manually call the orientation methods in viewDidLoad.  This is a bit of a hack but it's working fine so far.

In *viewDidLoad* I added this:

```
if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0") ) {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation duration:0.2f];
}
```

I've then added this in a common header file:

```
// iOS Version Checking
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

I got the iOS version checking defines from an answer [to this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version).

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced a similar issue and had to override it in the tabbarcontroller derived class to get this to work:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [_tabBarConroller willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same problem and have been pulling my hair out. I've finally discovered a solution but unfortunately this will be iOS 5.0 + only:

Place the following code in your `viewDidLoad` method in your custom `UIViewController`:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.1f;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
});
```

This will push the rotation update to the next run loop. `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` is an iOS 5.0+ call.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 5 and higher you should build you view controllers hierarchy (using *-addChildViewController:*). Then child view controllers begin to call *-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation:* and other interface related methods again (because parent controller will notify them about UI orientation changes).

Please, do not use any 'dirty' methods.

Useful documentation:
[Apple docs about 'addChildViewController:'](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController%3a)