# How do I check if a device is running iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

How do I check if a device is running iOS 6? I need to check to see if the os is iOS 6 in order to change my youtube video urls because of the release notes from Apple on how to handle them in iOS6

> As of iOS 6, embedded YouTube URLs in the form of
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0 will no longer work. These
>   URLs are for viewing the video on the YouTube site, not for embedding
>   in web pages. Instead, the format that should be used is described in
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters.

I was thinking of an if else statement to handle this.

thanks for any help

Comment: Let me refer you to [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)...

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version

Comment: take the macro defined here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8042056/593336

Comment: @mayuur macro only work on compile time, meaning that if you compile with iOS 6 it will use the iOS 6 way. But running the same app on iOS 5 it will still be using the iOS 6 way. Run time checking would be better.

Comment: @hanumanDev what actually you want to do...!!!!

Comment: @rckoenes Is it so? I didn't know that. But that problem wouldn't come up if I run it after a complete cleanup and reset the simulator right?

Comment: @mayuur yes, a marco is compile time. Thus recompiling it with an other SDK wil work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As Before comparing float parameters you should put 6.0 in a float variable so that LHS and RHS should be the same to compare:

```
float currentVersion = 6.0;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion)
{
    NSLog(@"Running in IOS-6");
}
```

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] is probably the most inefficient way of checking for iOS version numbers. 

Its not clear why, but this function takes precious CPU cycles to return a version number. 

Use NSFoundationVersionNumber instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *versionString = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]; // iOS version as string
int versionStringInt = [ver intValue]; // iOS version as int
float versionStringFloat = [ver floatValue]; // iOS version as float
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
 float deviceVersion   = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
 NSLog(@"My Device version is :%f ",deviceVersion);
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: You might want to do something like `if (deviceVersion >= 6.0)` because as soon as 6.1 rolls out , that code will fail and assume its on 5.x again.

Comment: Checking for an explicit version number is almost always wrong. Check for capabilities instead.

Comment: hey @Shayne you are right but here i just show that i am also not favor for above that's why ik am modifying my answer.

Comment: @Roger So how *do* you check for capabilities instead? For example Using the new `UIActivityViewController` in IOS6 for social sharing functions, and calling `TWTweetComposeViewController` and email sharing manually when its not supported ?