# Adapting Mapkit apps

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am developing an app that uses MapKit. In view of the Apple announcements of June 11, 2012, will I have to totally rewrite it, using a new API, in order to keep up with these changes?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964585/should-i-be-worried-about-rumors-that-apple-will-stop-using-google-maps-in-ios6/10964615#10964615

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 is still under NDA, just a quick answer that doesn't reveal any NDAd information:
no you won't, the API for existing MapKit stuff  stays the same on iOS 6.