# Can I still use Google Maps in iOS 6 and up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview, ios6

As you may know Apple recently announced iOS 6 and with it their own new maps.
I just ran my app on the new version iOS and it uses as standard maps in `MKMapView` the new Apple Maps.
It is probably awesome but my app is *relying* on Google Maps, because I use their data and routes.
Is there any way I can still use Google Maps instead of Apple's own version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964585/should-i-be-worried-about-rumors-that-apple-will-stop-using-google-maps-in-ios6 Similar post

Comment: @Adrian your are right its related but not it is not answering my question. My app still works fine and everything works but it shows everything on the new apple map BUT I am required to show this data on a google map otherwise I am not allowed to use the data. So my question is how do I get back google maps in iOS 6

Comment: I don't think there is going to be an option for that. In my opinion Apple changed GoogleMaps to their own implementation exactly because they (Apple) don't want people to use Google stuff anymore (or at least not as much as now). If you want/need to use GoogleMaps you will need to make your own thing using an UIWebView, etc. :(

Comment: @nacho4d wow this would blow big time. this means I would have to redo my whole app cause it is based on google geocoding and directions api.

Comment: You can log in here to see more information about the new maps system https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html but it is still under NDA so cannot be discussed here.

Comment: There is solution: https://github.com/mladjan/GoogleMapsOverlayiOS

Comment: @kondormit this is awesome thank you so much. Did you try and submit an app with that? Does apple allow this? Or does it get rejected?

Comment: @bllubbor I will submit my app "Taksiko" with this update these days, I will tell you for about 10 days did they accepted update.

Comment: @kondormit I think it's gonna be rejected, because instead of Google logo there is "Legal" link. When using Google maps, google logo must be at least visible with no objects over it.

Comment: I will put Google logo and legal link of course :)

Comment: @kondormit - how's Your app doing these days? I saw it on AppStore and tried to check it out myself, unfortunately it asks me for mobile number. Does doing the trick with Google Tiles + Google trademark on maps went any good? Is it right approach?

Comment: @SebastianŁuczak It's approved by Apple and it works well :)

Comment: @kondormit these are awesome news. I have one more question though how did you get rid of the little legal button in the corner and did show the google logo? Could you ad that to your github project? that would be awesome. thanks

Comment: @bllubbor just updated github repo, check it out :)

Comment: @kondormit your are the best thank you so much!

Comment: @bllubbor np, you are welcome :)

Comment: Man what is the deal with closing perfectly reasonable questions? This is why Quora has a chance. Google has just recently released an SDK to allow developers to utilize their maps. You need to register for a key however, and they are rolling out these somewhat slowly it seems.

Comment: @Stunner i have applied for key at the google maps api console, but didn't get any response yet! and am here while searching for a solution for my problem! its really bad to know that these people close such important questions without checking whether its important or not! always rushing to flag! strange

Comment: Yeah... it's as if they have nothing better to do with their time. Rather than help out, they would opt to burden others. I am waiting for a key as well... It just recently launched so my hopes are high that we will get them sometime after the holidays are over.

Comment: @kondormit "*It's approved by Apple*" - Has it also been approved by Google? According to their [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq) it's against the rules to access map tiles without going through their API.

Comment: @kondormit looks like the "legit" way of doing it would be to use the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example). See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#mapsformobile).

Comment: Use GoogleMaps SDK for iOS now, it's legal and nice vector maps.

Comment: anyone have received the GoogleMaps ios sdk api key?