# How to use Google Map Api in iOS6

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I still use google maps in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992595/can-i-still-use-google-maps-in-ios-6)

Is there any alternate for using Google Map API or Google Map in iOS6 . coz iOS6 support apple map and what if i have an iphone app that uses google map api in its current version. and if i want that app to run on iOS6 so i have to convert that map from google to apple map? i just want to ask that how can i use Google Map in iOS6? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You still can use Google Maps, however, any links that open maps using Google API will open in a browser, and not in the built in Maps view.