# ios 5 and ios6 compatibility features -xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, release, beta, ios6-maps

I want to create a map based app but apple will no longer user google maps in ios 6.I dont want to upgrade to the developer beta yet as I am waiting for the final release. But I also want to get started as soon as possible. If I start my project now will it change or the code will differ when the ios 6 is available? In other words if I make a successful built in ios 5 will it be unsuccessful when i upgrade to ios6? Will I have to rewrite the entire thing or everything will be compatible resulting to an also successful built? thank you in advance..

Comment: take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964585/should-i-be-worried-about-rumors-that-apple-will-stop-using-google-maps-in-ios6/10964830#10964830) for some thoughts on this

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work fine.
Almost nothing changes with iOS 6 and MKMapKit in terms of code.
The only thing which works different in iOS 6 is the way you call the native Map App from inside you app. (if you are using this functionality)

Comment: i might use this.. how will this be different?

Comment: In pre iOS 6 you use url-schemes to call the native map application. (openURL http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London)
On iOS 6 this will launch safari. So you will need to implement both versions for <= iOS 5 and iOS 6+.
Since the iOS 6 version is under NDA a can't tell you here how it works, but if you have a Developer account look for `MKMapItem` in the  [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapItem).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wait to use beta versions of XCode, you place them in different locations on your hard drive and leave the current XCode in place.

Then you can test in the iOS 6 simulator just to make sure it works as well as on iOS 5.