# Map Integration in ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, ios6-maps

How can I integrate maps in iOS 6. Will it be supported in earlier iOS versions?

I want to display a map in an app which has to support iOS 5 and newer. How could I do this? In the earlier versions iOS uses Google Maps and in the latest version it uses its own map.

Will anybody help me out?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10964585/730701).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some differences on the versions of the framework for iOS 6 and for below iOS 6. I've noticed that the offset value of the annotations is different from

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there ever was a Google Maps API kit.

Every time a map from Google showed up in an iPhone app, it was through the iOS MapKit API. I think Google was only the maps provider. What they did in iOS 6 was changing their map provider for themselves. So I think upgrading to MapKit in iOS 6 will just require a little maintenance, and not a full rewrite. I'm guessing most of it will run fine on iOS 5.

*Note : this is just my own guess, I haven't looked into developing for iOS 6 yet.*

Answer (score 1):

For all I've seen MapKit is essentially the same. Under iOS 5 the default map provider will be Google, under iOS 6 it will be Apple. If you specify a custom map provider that will be used in either. Just be sure to test properly in iOS 5.0, 5.1 & 6.

Comment: Will I be able to put custom images in annotation view in mapview?