# Opening Maps App with Current Location & Directions in iOS 5

Tags: google-maps, ios5, ios4, core-location

Hi I tried using this to open the maps app with current location and get directions to whatever I put for the directions. When I click the button on my iPhone nothing happens but it's being clicked. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@ %@ %@ %@",
                     streetString , cityString, stateString, zipString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Comment: If you type in that exact same URL into Mobile Safari, does a map come up as you desired?  Also, why don't you want to use the built-in MapKit framework?  Switching out to Safari from your app might not be the behavior your users would want to see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invoke iPhone Maps for Directions with Current Location as Start Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576768/how-to-invoke-iphone-maps-for-directions-with-current-location-as-start-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're escaping the the NSString using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/mapssaddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@ %@ %@ %@", streetString , cityString, stateString, zipString];
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```