# Adding a label to Destination Address when opening Apple Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-maps

What I want to do is allow the user to open Apple Maps and have it automatically open the `Directions` form for them to get directions to my location.

The destination is a Latitude/Longitude pair. I am doing this:

```
NSString *addressString = @"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=50.894967,4.341626&dirflg=d";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:addressString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This opens Apple Maps as I expect. However, in the destination field, it shows the Latitude/Longitude pair. I would like to specify this label. Here is what I mean:

[image]

Is there anyway I can replace the coordinates with a label using URL params?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what want to achieve. Could you explain it some more?

Comment: @joern in the screenshot, the "End:" field automatically populates to "50.894967, 4.341626" but I want to be able to specify some other text to go into this field (the name of the location I am navigating the user to)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Location to get the **current location** and after you can set your *`"Start"`* point with that info. You don't have to set *`"End"`* point.

Please check this link, I'm sure you'll find its useful;

> [How to invoke iPhone Maps for Directions with Current Location as Start Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576768/how-to-invoke-iphone-maps-for-directions-with-current-location-as-start-address)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the way you want. But it give us more flexibility to open the  Map app. That is using `[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:]` to ask the Map to open the address. The screen looks a bit different from what you might expect though.

```
CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:50.894967 longitude:4.341626];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 10000, 10000);
NSDictionary *addressDict = @{
        (NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey : @"Any Name",
};
MKPlacemark *destinationPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location.coordinate addressDictionary:addressDict];
MKMapItem *destinationMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlacemark];

[destinationMapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[destinationMapItem]
               launchOptions:@{
                       MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                       MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey : [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:region.span]
               }
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use core location  for current location, and start, no end needed though